# (as3, flash) hide the design after the preloading, and show it after the methods (from the .as) are ready?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, resize, preloader

at the end of the preload, and for 1/2 second approximately, the design from the "fla" appears on screen but with the elements as they are in the fla, and then they take their right position, as set in the .as file : because the elements need to know the size of the window.

For example : in the fla, i drew a square of 10x10 in blue that becomes a flag of 10x stage.stageWidth after we know the size of the user's window.

Is there a solution to avoid to see the elements before they are not at their "right" size?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the art from your FLA (what you put on your stage using the GUI) is loading before the code executes that resizes/repositions it.

Where does your Actionscript reside? Is it on a later frame in the timeline, after the art appears? Make sure any code that deals with resizing the art to the stageWidth will execute before the art appears, in terms of the playhead running through the timeline of your SWF.

You can hide art on the stage through Actionscript by giving it an instance name (ex., "myMovieClip") and calling:

myMovieClip.alpha = 0;

then run your resizing code followed by

myMovieClip.alpha = 1;

Hope this helps.

Note you can also just set your MovieClip to alpha=0 in the GUI if the concern is that the code is separate from the FLA. Then just change it to alpha=1 in whatever method you want that to run in.

Comment: thanks, yeah it worked when i put the whole design in a movieclip, and "addChild" the movieclip after the resize method is called. thanks